# In order to keep counting step, which one is better between Alarm manager and Work manager?

Tags: android, kotlin

I make app keep counting steps on `Foreground Service`.

Since foreground service with persisting `notification` can work on background and is not affected by Doze mode or standby mode, I assume all is finished.

However when I test this, after a couple of days, it stopped.

As I searched on this issue, I found that android itself can kill background job due to CPU, memory, battery etc..

So I get suggestion to use `Work manager` or `Alarm manager` to check notification appears or not on period, and if not, call foreground service again.

First I use alarm manager,It works perfect but also after 2days, one device among four test devices stopped.

```
 alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val repeatInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES
    val triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + repeatInterval
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        triggerTime,
        repeatInterval,
        pendingIntent
    )
```

Here, I use `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`, so I assume it can wake up device from `doze mode`, but I think it couldn't? (I don't know why alarm manager stopped after 2days still)

So I change it to `Work manager` and now testing..

```
 val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        val periodicWorkRequest: PeriodicWorkRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<RegisterAlarmWorker>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).build()

        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            UNIQUE_WORK_NAME,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            periodicWorkRequest
        )
```

---

But when I look up this background work issue more, I learn that Work manager can't wake up doze mode, it defer the work until doze mode is finished.

Then it can't count steps when device is on doze mode.

So Work manager is not suitable for this purpose i think?

And from document, it says Alarm manager to use during doze mode, it needs to be set as `setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`.

Then I conclude that

1. Alarm manager is better than Work manager for this purpose to check something on period.
2. I need to change `setInexactRepeating` to `setAndAllowWhileIdle` in Alarm manager.

Is this right?

**But** when I check with `Work manager` and make my emulator to go doze mode with this code,

```
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

Work Manager keeps working well during idle mode.

Then.. it is different from what document says..!

So I'm confused should I change Work manager to Alarm manager or not.

Background work is all getting mysterious to me.. T_T

please help me.